# Dictionary value of key from another array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

**This has been answered... have to wait 2 days to accept own answer**

---

**Background:**

I have an array ("arr") generated from a dataset in Excel; I use that array to populate another array ("zrr"), where one aspect of that population is to use a Dictionary ("dcdept").

The dictionary was populated appropriately (tested via `debug.print dcdept(ActualKey)`; was populated such that `dcdept(4000)="Value"` and tested `debug.print dcdept(4000)` printed the word "Value" in the immediate window.

I was originally using the source dataset via `.cells(i,)` references, but with several hundred thousand lines, I tried to keep activities in VBA to speed it up.

There are no errors/alerts generated from my code.

---

**Issue:**

When attempting to populate an element in zrr (`zrr(i-1,3)`) using the dictionary key from arr (`dcdept(arr(i-2,16))`), I get no value output.

---

**Question:**

Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions to resolve the issue with the given data?

---

**Code in question:**

```
Public arr As Variant, brr As Variant, crr As Variant, drr As Variant, lrs As Long
Private Sub changes()
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, y As String, z As String, dcdept As Scripting.Dictionary, zrr As Variant, a As Long
    'set-up dictionary for department
    Set dcdept = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dcdept(4000) = "Value"
    'generate array to store new values
    With Sheets("Conversion")
        .Columns(16).NumberFormat = "0"
        lrs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrs, 17)).Value '17 = Q
        ReDim zrr(lrs, 4)
        For i = 2 To lrs
            ReDim Preserve zrr(lrs, 4)
            Select Case Left(arr(i - 1, 17), 3)
                Case "QTE"
                    x = 7
                Case "ZNA"
                    x = 5
            End Select
            zrr(i - 2, 0) = Right(arr(i - 1, 17), x)
            If InStr(arr(i - 1, 9), " Milestone ") Then
                y = Left(arr(i - 1, 9), 2) & " " & arr(i - 1, 10)
            Else
                y = arr(i - 1, 9) & " " & arr(i - 1, 10)
            End If
            zrr(i - 2, 1) = y
            If IsEmpty(arr(i - 1, 14)) Then
                zrr(i - 2, 2) = "N"
            Else
                zrr(i - 2, 2) = "Y"
            End If
            a = Val(arr(i - 1, 16))
            z = dcdept(a)
            zrr(i - 2, 3) = z
            Debug.Print a
            Debug.Print z
        Next i
        'append data to sheet
        .Cells(2, "R").Resize(lrs, 3).Value = zrr  'SHOULD BE Resize(lrs,4), per answer
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this line `zrr(i-1,3) = dcdept(arr(i-2,16))` is adding a new item to the dictionary - can you check in the locals window. You could instead loop through the dictionary items?

Comment: @SJR thanks for the input; it doesn't appear (from the testing) that the dictionary itself is being affected/appended.  Trying to type that loop into the code now to see if that fixes this.  Most all of my testing sends me back to thinking I have an issue with my data that I can't seem to make sense from... the sheet is initially formatted with `@`, otherwise i get errors trying to transpose an array greater than 9101 rows, then i set certain columns back to `"yyyy/mm/dd"` or `"0"`.

Comment: @SJR just did another test with `debug.print` and this looks tied to writing back into the array `zrr`

Comment: I'm not sure if you've tested for it, but in a dictionary, the type of the key matter. So there will be a difference between `dcdept(4000)` and `dcdept("4000")`. If the values were read into the array as text, then it won't recognize an integer value of the key. If you've tested for that, I'm having a bit of trouble identifying the issue. Any chance you could post more of the relevant code so we can follow along?

Comment: Also, in addition to the prior comment, simply looking at `.numberformat` won't give you the type of the data. Try using a `VarType(arr(i, 10))` (or whatever the index is) to see what type the value in the array is being stored as

Comment: @user3561813 put 'Debug.Print VarType(arr(i - 1, 16))' and every vartype is `8`.  I even took `Val()` out of my testing and `a = drr(i - 1, 16)` when printed is `4000`, then `z = dcdept(a)` printed is `Value`.

Comment: @Cyril `Vartype = 8` means that the value in the array is a `String`. If the keys that are added to the dictionary are integers, then it will not find them

Comment: @user3561813 updated the code to help follow along the whole process i'm using.  regarding your last comment, if `debug.print z` where `z = dcdept(arr(i-1,16))` displays the correct value, then the vartype for is/expectation should be sufficient?  The issue appears to be writing that value into `zrr`

Comment: @Cyril. I misunderstood. If `z` contains the value "Value", then it should be added to the array. I ran a quick test to confirm on my end, and it seemed to work.

Comment: @user3561813 i just ran a smaller test and yes, i can get my dictionary entry to append to another array, then print the value to ensure it is there.  Just did something that's really pissing me off, about to update *again* for what seems like i screwed something up when dimensioning `zrr`

Comment: FUCK MY LIFE... all of that effort and confusion because I didn't resize appropriately... `.Cells(2, "R").Resize(lrs, 3).Value = zrr`  should be `.Cells(2, "R").Resize(lrs, 4).Value = zrr`.  if i had a duck i would throw it right now

Comment: I just saw that in your code as well. I literally smacked myself on the forehead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot...

```
.Cells(2, "R").Resize(lrs, 3).Value = zrr
```

should be

```
.Cells(2, "R").Resize(lrs, 4).Value = zrr
```

---

Can't accept my own answer for 2 days; pardon the "unanswered" question in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is not an answer, but an illustration of my comment. I didn't expect this to happen. I set up a simple scenario which I hope is similar to yours:

```
Sub x()

Dim oDic As Object, v1(1 To 2), v2(1 To 2), v, i As Long

Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

v1(1) = "Fred"
v1(2) = 1000

oDic(1) = v1(1) 'key 1, item "Fred
oDic(2) = v1(2) 'key 2, item 1000
```

The locals window after this looks like this

[image]

---

Then add this line

```
v2(1) = oDic(v1(1))
```

and the immediate window reads thus:

[image]

---

Add this line

```
v2(2) = oDic(v1(2))
```

and the immediate window reads thus:

[image]

Comment: That's some interesting information... if i'm understanding correctly, this would indicate that the use of the v2 variant does in fact create new entries in the oDic library.  What would be a workaround for outputting the value given a key?  i have attempted to use the suggested loop (excel keeps crashing when i try for j = 0 to dcdept.count, if dcdept.keys(j) = arr(i-1,16) then z = dcdept.keys(j), exit for)

Comment: Resolved the matter of stupidity and this is fixed.  Thanks again for the input and the listed lesson on how some of these dictionaries are functioning.